# html elements don't display in php file

Tags: php, html, pdo

I can't figure out why the html elements don't display in the php file I created. A google search on this question don't show any results or either in this forum. In my other php files the html elements display.

I'm thinking that I may be doing something that I'm not aware of that's causing this problem. I compared the php file in question to other php files with html but I don't see any difference. The other php files display html content. I wonder if anybody else ever experienced this problem.

I've been at it for some hours now. I would greatly appreciate some help, or suggestions here. Here is the php file and I'm also going to show the database connect php file because it seems like the index page is redirecting to this file because in the browser "Connected Successfully" is echoed from the page.

index.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'debase.php';
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDO Login<title>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Student Name</h2>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a><br>
    <table border="1px" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY name_id");
            $stmt->execute(); 
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($result as $row){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['user_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
           }
        ?>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the database php file.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=item';$username='swydell';$password='Ontime100$';
try{
    $conn = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected Successfully\n"."<br>";
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed". $e->getMessage();
    include('database_error.php');
    //conn = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: what does viewing your HTML source reveal? and why are you using `ob_start();` and `session_start();` at all? and what do you mean by *"because it seems like the index page is **redirecting** to this file"*. Question's too unclear for me.

Comment: seems like you're only responding to answers then. I stayed here long enough and feel ignored. Wishing you well with this; I've left the question. You'll need to continue on with the people who gave you answers. I post a comment to get clarification and that's what they're for.

Comment: What I mean is that in the browser I see "Connected Successfully" which is the message I  echoed in the database.php file.

Comment: My page source code reveals the html content, starting with the "Connected Successfully ",which is echoed from the databse.php file, and shows the <table>, <th>,<td> tags.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `debase.php` =/= `database.php`

Comment: You turned on `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` but you are not running your db access code in a try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is you have `ob_start()` before your HTML output which buffers output to the client. You can try add `ob_end_flush()` at the end to send it to the client.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: I removed the spaces in the database file. And I added ob_end_flush(); at the end of the file. I still don't see my html content.

Comment: or not buffer at all, as there seems no point in doing so here.

Comment: I commented out ob_start(); The html content still doesn't show in the browser.

Comment: Can you try commenting out your Database stuff in the HTML to see whether there is an issue with getting the connection? Also comment out the `echo "Connected Successfully\n"."<br>";` from your Database file.

Comment: I commented out echo "Connected Successfully". I commented out the database connection and now I see a blank page. But the page source shows all  the html elements.

Comment: Another issue is that when I run other pages I get redirected to the index.php page where the table elements are. I just see a blank page in the browsers. I tried firefox and chrome.

Comment: I think you may have some environment/configuration issues. What are you running? LAMP? WAMP? Self install/configuration? Perhaps some code is missing. Are you showing all relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>` after your HTML to send the output to the browser and display it.

By calling `ob_start()` on line 4 you're preventing the script from having any output.

More at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: I want to mention that this problem seems to be isolated to this application /project because when I run other php files with html content from another project I see the html content. In addition this project redirects to the index.php file no matter what page I run. 
Everything redirects to my index file.